# array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given

Tags: php, arrays

I have this bit of code:

```
if( array_key_exists('customtextcolor',$atts) ){
    // If in array, then check if none, if not none, add to CSS classes
    if ( 'none' !== $atts['customtextcolor'] ) {
        $custstyles[] = $atts['customtextcolor'];
    }       
}
```

Which is on line 90, and my **php.log** shows an error on line 90.

> Apr  2 08:46:16 #####.net ool www: PHP Warning:  array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in /var/www/####/wp-content/plugins/Fusion-Builder-Custom-Text-For-HP/fusion-builder-custom-text-for-hp.php on line 90

Which I thought was strange, because I was sure it is was an array, because the code works as expected. I also used `echo gettype($atts);` and it returns an array. When I `var_dump($atts);` it renders the full array.

Any idea what php.log is showing this error message?

If `$atts` is a string, why does `gettype()` identify it as an array? And why does `var_dump()` render it as an array?

I've looked at the other `array_key_exists()` questions on StackOverflow, but they aren't the same issue as far as I can tell.

Comment: As the error suggests, `$atts` is a `string` instead of an `array`....

Comment: Hi @nytrix that's why I used gettype() and var_dump() to validate, $atts is an array. Unless it changes types throughout - which would be strange.

Comment: There must be some circumstance that causes a string to be written to `$atts` at least on one call. There's little to do other than more in-depth `varr_dump()`'ing of it to narrow down how and when this happens.  PHP definitely will not produce that error unless `$atts` is truly not an array at the moment that executes.

Comment: Yes, it can, depending on your code. I don't see any of the previous code, so I can't see where it changes to a `string`. Or in a certain case you might enter a `string` instead of a `array` in which case you have to to some extensive debugging.

Comment: Okay got it. I will try to add it to the function return value, and see if that makes the gettype() easier to see.

Answer (score 6):

Change the if condition as below:

`if(is_array($atts) && array_key_exists('customtextcolor', $atts))`

This will check if `$atts` is an array at first then will check the `array_key_exist` operation.

Answer (score -3):

Just write the following line of code:

```
 array_key_exists('customtextcolor', (array) $atts);
```

This will [cast](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) the `$atts`-variable into an array if it's not already an array.

---

You can also just check if there is an array with a value per:

`isset($atts['customtextcolor']);`

Comment: This makes no sense. It is a blind attempt to fix something without understanding it. If OP clearly claims the variable should contain an array. Either it does, then your cast does nothing, or it does not, then one should try to find out what is wrong instead of blindly trying a type case.

Comment: Thank you very much. This did resolve the errors, but I'm still confused why this happened in the first place. I'll leave it be, but strange. Thank you!!